# i am trying to extend a html file in flask but its not reflecting in output?

Tags: python, html, templates, flask, jinja2

I am new to Flask. I started from some Youtube videos,but somehow mine is not working with the **extends**  part. I am getting the output as if I haven't extended the second HTML file specified below. Am I missing something ?

This is my "**main.py**" file

```py
from flask import Flask,redirect,url_for,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("home.html")


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is "**templates/home.html**" file

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>mY Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> this is nav----------- bar</h1>
    <hr/>
    {% include 'templates/test.html' %}
    <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is 2nd html "**templates/test.html**"

```html
{% extends 'templates/home.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Index</h1>
  <p class="important">
    Welcome on my awesome homepage.
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `templates/` part is not required for `extends`.

Just use:
`{% extends 'home.html' %}`

in place of:
`{% extends 'templates/home.html' %}`

and it should work.